# How to prove this theorem using the field axioms?

Tags: abstract-algebra

I need to prove that if $ab=ac$ and $a\ne0$ then $b=c$. I'm guessing that it has to do with the existence of inverse axiom $xy=1$.

Comment: What happens if you multiply both sides of $ab=ac$ by $a^{-1}$?

Comment: You obviously would get a=b but I'm wondering how did we use the field axioms to get there

Comment: The field axioms tell you that every non-zero element has an inverse. You're also using associativity of multiplication.

Comment: if $a \neq 0$ there exists an inverse for a

Comment: To apply the above, you must **also** us a rather important though elementary property or equalities/equations: if you carry on the very same mathematical operation on both sides of the equality, the equality is preserved.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are working in a field so every nonzero element has a multiplicative inverse. Thus, multiplying both sides on the left by $a^{-1}$ gives $a^{-1}ab=a^{-1}ac$ which is b=c.